# Checking if variable from a list exists in imported file

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a simple iterative code that goes through a list of variables and checks it from a file.

For example, it could have 2 variables `foo1` and `foo2`, and I could do the following

```py
try:
  from file import foo1
except ImportError:
  foo1 = None

try:
  from file import foo2
except ImportError:
  foo2 = None
```

...and so forth. However, now my list of variables are getting long.   Is there an easier way to put my variables (i.e. `foo1`, `foo2`, `foo3`, etc) into a list and try to see if it exists in "file" instead of repeating this try-catch process?

I tried the following, but it didn't work, especially when foo1 or foo2 did exist.

```
my_list = ['foo1', 'foo2']

for listElem in my_list:
    try:
        from file import listElem
    except ImportError:
        print ("Can't find",listElem,"in file")
```

Thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why are you doing this? And why don't you just `import file` then run `dir(file)` and see if members of your list are in there?

Comment: why does your file contain so many variables. It should probably just contain one list which you can then easily import `from file import myList`

Comment: Good question.  It started off when we were importing variables from a file.  We took for granted that there variables were always there.  But now the files that we import don't always have the variables.  So now I have a mix of mandatory variables and optional variables and I need to know if the optional variables are present and I can't import non-existant var.

I went down that path (import file) as well (sort of)...  but I didn't try out dir(file).  When you use dir(file), I guess I could scan its output to see if my variable is listed.  And then I guess after that I would import it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import file

my_list = ['foo1', 'foo2']

for listElem in my_list:
    if not (value := getattr(file, listElem, None)):
       print ("Can't find",listElem,"in file")
    globals()[listElem] = value
```

[`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) is a dictionary that contains all top-level names. What we do in the above snippet is to create global variables using the names from `my_list`.